# Asymptotic expansion of a solution to an IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

I'm reading a paper, and am trying to figure out the details of an argument for the asymptotic expansion of a solution to the following IVP:

$$\cosh(t)u(t) -\sinh(t)u'(t) = \sqrt{\sinh^2(t) + [u(t)]^2 -M\hspace{2pt} \frac{\sinh^3(t)}{u(t)}}, \hspace{20pt} u(0) = 1.$$

The author says that it is easy to show that the asymptotic expansion of the solution is $$u(t) = 1 +\frac{M}{3!}t^3 + \mathcal O(t^4).$$

If you assume that the solution is of the form $u(t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{u^{(k)}(0)}{k!}t^k$, one can try to differentiate the ODE and evaluate at $t=0$ to solve for $u^{(k)}(0)$, but this seems unreasonably messy, albeit doable.

I have also tried to express both sides as an infinite series using Taylor expansions.  For example, my calculation of the left-hand side yields 
\begin{align*}
\cosh(t)u(t) -\sinh(t)u'(t) &= \Big(1 + \frac{1}{2}t^2 + \mathcal O(t^4)\Big)\Big(1 + u'(0)t + \frac{u''(0)}{2}t^2 + \frac{u'''(0)}{3!}t^3 + \mathcal O(t^4)\Big)\\
& \hspace{20pt}- \Big(t + \frac{1}{3!}t^3 + \mathcal O(t^5) \Big)\Big(u'(0) + u''(0)t + \frac{u'''(0)}{2}t^3 + \mathcal O(t^4) \Big)\\
&= 1  + \frac{u''(0) - 1}{2}\hspace{2pt}t^2 + \frac{2 u'''(0) + u'(0) - 3}{3!}\hspace{2pt}t^3 + \mathcal O(t^4). 
\end{align*}
One would do the same for the right-hand side and compare the coefficients.  However, the right-hand side seems quite difficult to write as a Taylor series, so I'm beginning to wonder if there is an easier way.

$\textbf{My Question:} $ Is there an easier way to calculate the asymptotic expansion of such a solution to the IVP than two methods that I have described?

Comment: You could also directly compute $u'(0)$ and $u''(0)$ by using the ODE. For $u'$ this is no problem, but for $u''$ you would need to differentiate the ODE one time. However, it looks "easier" than your methods.

Answer (score 0):

In Maple:

> de:= cosh(t)*u(t) - sinh(t)*D(u)(t) = sqrt(sinh(t)^2 + u(t)^2 - M * sinh(t)^3/u(t)):
>
> dsolve({de, u(0)=1}, u(t), series, order = 10);

$$u \left( t \right) =1+{\frac {M}{6}}{t}^{3}+{\frac {M}{60}}{t}^{5}-{
\frac {{M}^{2}}{144}}{t}^{6}+{\frac {M}{1680}}{t}^{7}-{\frac {7\,{M}^{
2}}{5760}}{t}^{8}+ \left( {\frac {M}{90720}}+{\frac {{M}^{3}}{1296}}
 \right) {t}^{9}+O \left( {t}^{10} \right)
$$

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't thought to throw it in Maple.